# Identifying whether the device is online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to make a html, javascript or jquery code that performs a random action if it is identified that the device is offline from the site. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the online status with:

```
navigator.onLine
```

Comment: When using this be aware: [`So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)